# how does operator overloading work in this code

Tags: c#

i made a mistake on how i posted my code it kind of showed that im lazy and i just want everything to be done for me,i want to learn about operator overloading in the code below and what this code is doing in the main program

```
static public explicit operator Int32(Vector v)
        {
            return v.Length;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            String res = "<";
            for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
                res += " " + elements[i];
            res += " >";
            return res;
        }

        public override bool Equals(Object v)
        {
            return (this == (Vector)v);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

the code implements a class of vectors, by overriding the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication of vectors and operators of equality / inequality. Take into account the operation where one operand - real or integer. Throw an exception in the case of coincidence of dimension vectors in operations.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{



    public class Vector
    {
        private Double[] elements;

        public Vector()
        {
            this.elements = null;
        }

        public Vector(Int32 size)
        {
            if (size < 0) throw new Exception("Invalid vetors size");        
            elements = new Double[size];
        }

        public Vector(params Double[] elements)
        {
            this.elements = elements;
        }

        public Vector(Vector v)
        {
            this.elements = v.elements;
        }

        public int Length
        {
            get
            {
                if (elements == null) return 0;
                return elements.Length;
            }
        }

        public Double this[int index]
        {
            get 
            {
                return elements[index];
            }
            set 
            {
                elements[index] = value;
            }
        }

        static public Vector operator+(Vector v1, Vector v2)
        {
            if (v1.Length != v2.Length)
                throw new Exception("size of vectors are different");
            Vector res = new Vector(v1.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
                res[i] = v1[i] + v2[i];
            return res;
        }

        static public Vector operator+(Vector v, Double d)
        {
            Vector res = new Vector(v.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++ )
                res[i] = v[i] + d;
            return res;
        }

        static public Vector operator +(Double d, Vector v)
        {
            return (v + d);
        }

        static public Vector operator -(Vector v, Double d)
        {
            Vector res = new Vector(v.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
                res[i] = v[i] - d;
            return res;
        }

        static public Vector operator -(Double d, Vector v)
        {
            Vector res = new Vector(v.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
                res[i] = d - v[i];
            return res;
        }

        static public Vector operator *(Vector v, Double d)
        {
            Vector res = new Vector(v.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < v.Length; i++)
                res[i] = v[i] * d;
            return res;
        }

        static public Vector operator *(Double d, Vector v)
        {
            return (v * d);
        }

        static public Vector operator -(Vector v1, Vector v2)
        {
            if (v1.Length != v2.Length)
                throw new Exception("size of vectors are different");
            Vector res = new Vector(v1.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
                res[i] = v1[i] - v2[i];
            return res;
        }

        static public Vector operator *(Vector v1, Vector v2)
        {
            if (v1.Length != v2.Length)
                throw new Exception("size of vectors are different");
            Vector res = new Vector(v1.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < res.Length; i++)
                res[i] = v1[i] * v2[i];
            return res;
        }

        static public Boolean operator ==(Vector v1, Vector v2)
        {
            if (v1.Length != v2.Length)
                return false;            
            for (int i = 0; i < v1.Length; i++)
                if(v1[i] != v2[i]) return false;
            return true;
        }

        static public Boolean operator !=(Vector v1, Vector v2)
        {
            return (!(v1 == v2));
        }

        static public explicit operator Int32(Vector v)
        {
            return v.Length;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            String res = "<";
            for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
                res += " " + elements[i];
            res += " >";
            return res;
        }

        public override bool Equals(Object v)
        {
            return (this == (Vector)v);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Vector v1 = new Vector(new Double[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
            Vector v2 = new Vector(2, 3, 4, 5);
            Console.WriteLine(v1 + " + " + v2 + " = " + (v1 + v2));
            Console.WriteLine(v1 + " - " + v2 + " = " + (v1 - v2));
            Console.WriteLine(v1 + " * " + v2 + " = " + (v1 * v2));
            Console.WriteLine(v1 + " * " + 7 + " = " + (v1 * 7));
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how the operator overloading works expecially in this code

Comment: @user1722962: You've posted nearly 200 lines of code. Post a *short* example which *only* demonstrates operator overloading being confusing. Also tell us exactly what about it confuses you - otherwise this question is too vague to answer, as we'd probably write the same sort of thing as you've hopefully already read in documentation.

Comment: It is done by the compiler, if operand A and operand B match one of the method signatures and the operation type, it calls that method as the overload instead of the default behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# all items are object so all inhere Object Class.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx

So all objects will have at least methods inhered from Object .
If you override any of this function like ToString the implementation of the function available on the base class will be replaced by your implementation.

For operators is the same situation,  moreover operator + for two arrays (or for other types defined by you)don't exist so they should have an implementation from you.

Operators are similar with methods 
static public Boolean operator ==(Vector v1, Vector v2)

need 2 Vector terms  and returns a Boolean  value
is equivalent (not on syntax) with: 
Boolean Equal(Vector v1, Vector v2)

Same approach for the rest.

I hope I was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

A little code-review, some big red flags here.

This constructor is dangerously wrong:

```
    public Vector(Vector v)
    {
        this.elements = v.elements;
    }
```

`elements` is a reference (to an array) so you are creating 2 Vector objects here that *share* the same elements.

```
Vector v1 = new Vector(10);
Vector v2 = new Vector(v1);  // 2 vectors, 1 elements

v1[0] = 1.2;
Console.WriteLine(v2[0]);  // prints 1.2
```

And this one is at least dangerous, for the same reasons:

```
    public Vector(params Double[] elements)
    {
        this.elements = elements;
    }
```

A remedy for these 2 (and probably a few more) issues would be to re-design this class to be immutable. For starters, remove the setter from the indexer.

This operator is very dubious, what is your use-case:

```
    static public explicit operator Int32(Vector v)
    {
        return v.Length;
    }
```

It suggests that a Vector somehow *is a length* , actually it just *has* a length.

Answer (score 2):

Operator overloads are quite simple, and based on the code provided, it looks like you understand it. What you may be running into a problem here is that for example here:

```
static public Vector operator *(Double d, Vector v)
    {
        return (v * d);
    }
```

you're defining the * operator with the operator itself, which is pointless and probably won't work anyway (multiplying a  Double d by a Vector v may work, but you're using the functionality already).

If you understand functions, operators do the same thing with two params and return the necessary values you want back.